# maven forgot about JAVA_HOME and not point to JRE

Tags: java, maven, ubuntu-18.04

I install Java 8, Maven and it was working properly, but after a few minutes it won't work. All the suggestions from "JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE" not works.

I get this output:

[image: first screen]
[image: second screen]

Comment: Clearly it is pointing to jre, not entire jdk dir

Comment: Remove the "/jre" from your `JAVA_HOME`. Maven needs the JDK. Not a JRE.